# Calabash iPhone Simulator Change TimeZone for different feature

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, calabash, calabash-ios

I want to use Calabash to run the `feature` in different timezones. Just to make sure that I am showing the correct data.

Is there any way that i can make use of the `tags @` to achieve what i want (To change the timezone in the simulator)?

First time using Calabash to write UI test for my app, not very sure how to set up the `launch.rb` Any help is appreciated.

Edit: There's one solution from [calabash-ios](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/Changing-Locale-and-Language) to change the locate at terminal, I would prefer it to be a `tag`.

`$ calabash-ios sim locale de-CH fr_CH`

Answer (score 0):

Add `system` before `calabash-ios sim locale de-CH fr_CH` inside your tag